# Icons not displayed as inline when resizing window to 480px or less

Tags: css, media-queries

Here's part of CSS code:

```
body {
width: 80%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.icons {
float:right;
width:5.2173913%;
height:60px;
margin:0 0.43478261%;
opacity:.5;
-webkit-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
-moz-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
-ms-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
-o-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
transition:opacity .1s ease-out
}

#title {
display:block;
background:url(title.jpg) no-repeat;
width:32.782609%;
height:95px;
margin:0.86956522% auto;
-webkit-transition:all .25s ease-out;
-moz-transition:all .25s ease-out;
-ms-transition:all .25s ease-out;
-o-transition:all .25s ease-out;
transition:all .25s ease-out
}
```

Heres is what the first part looks like:

[image]

When I try to add my `@media class:

```
@media screen and(max-width: 480px){
    #title {
    display:block;
    background:url(title_s.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:95px;
    margin:0.86956522% auto;
    -webkit-transition:all .25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all .25s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all .25s ease-out;
    -o-transition:all .25s ease-out;
    transition:all .25s ease-out
    }

    .icons {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height:60px;
    margin:0 5px;
    opacity:.5;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
    transition:opacity .1s ease-out
    }
}
```

it looks like this:

[image]

I don't understand why the icons won't be displayed as `inline`. I've tried `display:inline-block` as well.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/2bfhp/

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net. @Orangepill already covered the fact that you are changing the icons to `display:block` which would certainly not make those elements `inline` anymore.

Comment: @MatthewGreen http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/2bfhp/ here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

In my `@media screen and(max-width: 480px){` under `.icons`, I had to change change `display:block` to `display:inline-block` and set the width to it's original size in px.

So my `.icons` class would look like this:

```
.icons {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
width: 60px;
height:60px;
margin:0 5px;
opacity:.5;
-webkit-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
-moz-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
-ms-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
-o-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
transition:opacity .1s ease-out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the media queried css for .icon class  change `display:block;` to `display:inline;` and you will probably want to remove the width rule from there as well

```
.icons {
display: inline;
float: none;
height:60px;
margin:0 5px;
opacity:.5;
-webkit-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
-moz-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
-ms-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
-o-transition:opacity .1s ease-out;
transition:opacity .1s ease-out
}
```

Comment: exactly same result - I thought i wrote that in the original post. Sorry about that.

Comment: and change if you add a space after the and in the media query line?

Comment: if I remove the width - all the icons disappear.

Comment: I don't have a space after my 'and' either.

Comment: only thing the css validator is griping about is missing quotes around the background image urls but I can't imagine that causing a problem here

Comment: It's showing the image - so I wouldn't think that is the problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33309/discussion-between-nilzone-and-orangepill)